# Zend Framework PDF multiline problems

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf

I have a problem, with Zend_PDF multiline, my problem is that I **can't  write the entire text** to my pdf.My text looks like this: http://pastebin.com/f6413f664

But when I open my .pdf file, the text looks like this: http://screencast.com/t/1CBjvRodeZQd

And here is my code:

```
    public function pdfAction()
{
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

    $theID = ($this->_getParam('id') !== NULL) ? (int)$this->_getParam('id') : false;

    ($theID === false) ? $this->_redirect('/home') : false;

    //Information
    $info = $this->artists->artistInfo($theID);

    // Create new PDF 
    $pdf = new Zend_Pdf(); 
    $pdf->properties['Title'] = "TITLE";
    $pdf->properties['Author'] = "AUTHOR";

    // Add new page to the document 
    $page = $pdf->newPage(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4); 
    $pdf->pages[] = $page; 

    // Set font 
    $page->setFont(Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA), 8); 

    // Draw text
     foreach (explode("</p>", $info[0]['biography']) as $i => $line) {
       $page->drawText($line, 0, 820 - $i * 10, 'UTF-8');
     }

    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-pdf', true);
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=my-file.pdf', true);
    $this->getResponse()->setBody($pdf->render());
}
```

What I want to do, is for every `<p>` to have a break(`<br />`\n) and to display the entire text.

Any solutions guys?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
 // Draw text
 foreach (explode("</p>", $info[0]['biography']) as $i => $line) {
   $page->drawText($line, 0, 820 - $i * 10, 'UTF-8');
 }
```

Give this a try(didn't try it):

```
// Draw text    
$charsPerLine = 50;
$heightPerLine = 10;

$text = str_replace('<p>','',$info[0]['biography']);
$lines = array();

foreach (explode("</p>", $text) as $line) {
    $lines = array_merge(
                    $lines, 
                    explode(
                            "\n",
                            wordwrap($line, $charsPerLine, "\n")
                    )
    );
}

foreach ( $lines as $i=>$line ) {
    $page->drawText($line, 0, 820 - $i * $heightPerLine, 'UTF-8');
}
```

You obviously need to play with those 2 "constants" to get the best results.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah it works!But I have one more question, how can I put at the top befor the text, a title?

Comment: change the 820 in the code to ~800 and add another drawText call to print your title