# How to drawTextBlock in zend PDF

Tags: zend-framework, pdf-generation, drawtext, zend-pdf

I using ZendFW 1.7.2 in my project and need to save PDF file. i am success for use function `drawText` but some of my data is too long so i need it break line. Now i get a solution from 
http://devzone.zend.com/1776/creating-pdf-documents-with-zend-framework/
that use function `drawTextBlock` but when i test with it.It's can't success any always return errors
 `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend_Pdf_Page::drawTextBlock()`

I think it's relate problem with something configuration ?Anyone used to success on it? please share it to me, I am looking to see your reply soon.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Zend Framework?

Answer (score 3):

DrawTextBlock is not existing in Zend Framework as it is a proposal for a improvement by Nico Edtinger. See: http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Pdf+text+drawing+improvements+-+Nico+Edtinger

The solution provided on [Zend Framework PDF multiline problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330322/zend-framework-pdf-multiline-problems) probably will help you further.