# Zend PDF draw text with new line in variable

Tags: zend-framework, zend-pdf

I have a variable with the following content. Now I have to draw that text on a pdf file with Zend PDF but the new line is ignored. How can i draw the break?

```
$text = 'line1\nline2';
$page->drawText($text, 100, 100);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zend Framework PDF multiline problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330322/zend-framework-pdf-multiline-problems)

Comment: Definitely a duplicate. The short answer is that you need to manually split your strings and call the drawText() method multiple times.